# Openshift and external mysql db with node-mysql ( Error: connect ECONNREFUSED )

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, openshift

I'm using node js app with external mysql database. It work properly from localhost and other hosting but on openshift I've got this error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED.

```
        var mysql = require('mysql');
        var dbConfig =  {
            host : 'external.mysql.com',
            port : '3306',
            user : 'user',
            password : 'pass',
            database : 'test'
        };

        var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);
        connection.connect();
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM test ', function(err, rows, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
        });
        connection.end();
```

I'm also tried telnet external.mysql.com 3306 from openshift and it tell 
telnet: connect to address 12.34.56.78: Connection refused

Maybe there is some additional params for external connection in openshift

Answer (score 1):

You should make port forwarding to connect remotely services on openshift platform.

[Here](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift/) is the official tutorial and [video](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-the-port-forwarding-on-openshift/).

Comment: no , it doesn't help. It says **There are no available ports to forward for this application.**

Comment: @ohmyfgod sorry, there is mysql connection doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html , May you try, are you able to connect via another application remotely?

Comment: Thanks for link but as I told earlier I successfully made connection from this app  from other hosting.